# Creating a loop for several input files at once

Tags: r, loops

I have an R code

```
example.bed.file <- paste0(
    path.package("SeqKat"),
    "/extdata/LP6005334_DNA_H01.bed"
    );

seqkat(
    5,
    3.2,
    2,
    bed.file = example.bed.file,
    output.dir = ".",
    chromosome = "all",
    ref.dir = example.ref.dir,
    chromosome.length.file = example.chromosome.length.file
    );
```

This code demands an input file which here is `LP6005334_DNA_H01.bed`

I 63 input files all with `.bed` and different names

I want to have a loop to work over my input files without needing to put them one by one and run the code

Thank you for any help

Comment: Abstract the logic into a function which takes a filename as input, create a list of names, and then loop over that list with the function (or use something like `sapply`). It is a little dated perhaps, but this [R bloggers article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/09/perform-a-function-on-each-file-in-r/) might help.

Comment: Sorry I am very bad in coding that is why I asked my question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the functions that you have used return and their types but in general the approach you should take is write a function that works for one file.

```
read_file <- function(x) {
  example.bed.file <- paste0(path.package("SeqKat"),x)
  
  seqkat(5,3.2,2,
    bed.file = example.bed.file,
    output.dir = ".",
    chromosome = "all",
    ref.dir = example.ref.dir,
    chromosome.length.file = example.chromosome.length.file)
}
```

Now create a vector of all the file names that you want to read, you can do that using `list.files` which will collect all the files that end with `'.bed'` extension and pass the function that you wrote to it using `lapply`.

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern = '\\.bed', full.names = TRUE)
result <- lapply(file_names, read_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some starter code, you should be able to get it from here

```
path <- "directorypath"
files <- dir(path)
#read.csv as an example
result <- rep(NA, length(files))
for(i in 1:length(files){
file <- files[i]
result[i] <- read.csv(file)
}
```

Comment: Sorry how I then put this as input into the main code and ask for a loop over that?